# How to add a texture to only part of an 'image as Plane'?

Tags: texturing, image, shader-nodes

Nodes are like Chinese to me, but for what I want to do I know there is no other way than to use them.
I have modeled a Glass mug to which I have applied some decals with transparency. So far, so good. Now I would like some of them to be "gold" not black. I have this texture https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-gold-brushed-001/3175, I would like to apply to the letters and to a silhouette image of the pyramid to put behind the image that is used now.  (I would also like to replace the present lettering for a bolder version so that it will outline the gold letters).
I just don't know how to do it.
[image: This is the mug so far]
[image: This is the image I want to have in the gold texture]

Thanks for any help.

[image]

It is becoming obvious that my initial approach is not going to yield the wanted results.
Having multiple decals over one another is not rendering correctly under Cycles.
I'm uploading two images to illustrate that. The first is an actual render, the second is a screen capture in rendered view mode.
So I'm back to square one.
I'm wondering if it wouldn't be better to use a single image file With basically only two colors and an alpha channel. And from there, use nodes to separate the colors and ultimately apply the metallicity and roughness settings to one color and keep metallicity at zero and higher roughness to the other.
I will use the 3rd image shown here to experiment on that.
If anyone has any suggestion for the node settings, i'd appreciate.
I'm embarking in those tests with fear.
[image: Render with multiple decals]
[image: Screen capture (what I thought it would look like)]
[image: Image I plan on using for the next tests]

Comment: Hello, maybe pack your images and share your file?

Comment: Thanks Moonboots. What do you mean by 'pack'?

Comment: go into File > External Data > Pack Resouces, then save

Comment: Now I feel really stupid... how do I 'share' a file?

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform if the file is too heavy, like workupload.com for example

Comment: It's done. The file is shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be cleaner to do it in the material but if you want to do it with decals, just do this node setup for the golden layer: Plug the *Image Texture* into the *Alpha*, unplug it from the *Base Color*, instead use a gold orange, and put the *Metallic* value at 1 and lower down the *Roughness* value:

[image]

If you plan to use the cup material instead, you need to unwrap correctly your cup, then pile your different images with this kind of node setup, which are *Principled BSDF* nodes mixed through *Mix Shader* with the alpha of *Image Texture* nodes as factor:

[image]

Comment: I used decals because I didn't know how else to do it.
If there is a better way (or an alternate way) I'd like to know.
Because for this project it seams like going by the color and metallicity adjustments way can work fine. But I'd still like to know if it is possible to assign an actual texture to the image itself... for future projects.
I have been searching Youtube and the web for that and didn't find anything.
I'm sure others would like to know as well ;)
Any way, thanks so much for your answer I will try it out and see what I can do for my other decals (this is a work in progress).

Answer (score 0):

[image]This is it! I'm proud of myself. I got through it without my brain exploding. Without even a headache. Thanks in grate part to Clément Perrotte (Moonboots) who showed me the right direction. I just had to multiply his setup by two and add two color ramps and a mix shader. All that on a new single image instead of many decals (the one posted at the end of my last edit of the question).
So thanks again Clément.[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think that your setup is correct, you don't need to plug any ColorRamp, just choose the color in the Base Color of your Principled BSDF, and use the Alpha output of your Image Texture as factor of the Mix Shader. Also see my edit if you want to try to use the material of the cup itself instead of decals

Comment: Merci encore Clément. 
Quand il s'agit d'utiliser des nodes, j'avance à tâtons. À défaut d'être la meilleure solution, je suis quand-même fier d'en avoir trouvé une qui marche.
Je vais de ce pas essayer les solutions que tu suggères. Comme disait mon père quand je me blessais ou faisais une erreure... "c'est le métier qui rentre".

Comment: De rien ! Si tu es francophone n'hésite pas à rejoindre notre discord ou notre forum, les adresses figurent en-dessous de mes vidéos  ;)